# Blank cache entry after asynchronous JavaScript load in IE8

Tags: ajax, caching, internet-explorer-8, modernizr, yepnope

I'm using Modernizr in one of my projects. I want to test for the existence of placeholder before downloading a polyfill for it. Here's the code I'm using to accomplish this:

```
yepnope({
    test : Modernizr.input.placeholder,
    nope : '/js/jquery.placeholder.js',
    complete: function(){
        $('input, textarea').placeholder();
    }
});
```

I'm experiencing an odd issue with this. It works perfectly when I hit the page without loading any resources from cache, but if I refresh the page, I'm getting an undefined method error for the call to .placeholder().

Looking in the dev tools, an empty jquery.placeholder.js (from the cache) seems to be the culprit. I can verify in Fiddler that the second response is returning a 304, and sending an empty body, which means IE should have the right version in cache, but it is empty somehow. What could cause this behavior?

**EDIT:** If I add placeholder.js to the head, everything works fine all the time. Just thought I'd point that out.